# how to re-evaluate how many of an element there are after a for loop has completed?

Tags: javascript, html

```
const removeBtnCustom = document.querySelectorAll('.customRemove');
for(let g=0; g<removeBtnCustom.length; g++){
    removeBtnCustom[g].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const itemToDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.takeoffPRODUCTcardLoaded5');
        console.log(itemToDelete[g].innerText);
        itemToDelete[g].remove();
    })
}
```

above is the code I am questioning.

Currently I am trying to delete an item within a displayed list. My initial thought was that I would create a for loop to add event listeners to each button upon rendering. But If I start from anywhere but the end of the list going straight up in order... it gets all wonky.

for example:

```
   |         itemToDelete         | 
   |removeBtnCustom|
[0]|delete| lorem ipsum lorem ipsum        <- first click (works correctly)
[1]|delete| lorem ipsum lorem              <- second click (deletes 2) <- third click nothing
[2]|delete| lorem ipsum
```

First click delete @ index 0 -> Works! but after element at 0 is deleted if I click
the new element 0 (previously 1) it deletes element 1 instead of 0.

I think my issue is either a fundamental misunderstanding of the mighty for loop, or the fact that it gets the array initially before the for loop runs and it still thinks the length of `removeBtnCustom` is still 3 when it is in fact now 2 after an element has been deleted(since the button is deleted with the parent element).

now my main question:

what is a different method I could use to do this? Is it possible to re-run/evaluate the length of `removeBtnCustom` within the for loop?

If that Isnt possible is there a different way entirely to do this effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should call the function again everytime a deletion is made?
Since when you delete one item in the list, like 0 for example, 1 will then become 0 and so you must do that same loop everytime you delete something in the list so it points the buttons in the right direction.